# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me with this database error, I'm inserting data on a table named

```
subjectdetails(
    subjectid int primarykey,
    subject varchar(50),
    semid int //foreign key from the table semester
    departmentid int(11) // foreign key from the table department
)
```

Now, when i insert a subject it only shows the error on SEMID like the below error
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
(`studentcorner/subjectdetails`, CONSTRAINT `subjectdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`SEMID`) REFERENCES `semester` (`SEMID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 2):

The error is indicating that you have a foreign key constraint which cannot be satisfied. Specifically, you're trying to insert a `subjectdetails` entry with an invalid `semid` column.  The value you're using for `semid` is invalid because that value cannot be found inside the `semester` table.  I know this because your error message states as much.

To fix this error, ensure that the value you're trying to insert for the `semid` column actually exists in the `semesters` table first.

I would suggest going to the documentation and re-read the section on [Using Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).  The relevant quote from that page regarding your issue is this (emphasis mine):

> For storage engines supporting foreign keys, MySQL rejects any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table **if there is no a matching candidate key value in the parent table**.

Comment: Thanks..brother...i found the real error.it was in the field of the table semester..thanks for your suggestion really appreciate the...GOD BLESS u